Im Having Issues with unreal project not building
i have this problem yesterday it worked perfectly i slept on it and boom the project dosent build.
This is the code from Microsoft.Makefile.targets
  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForNMakeBuild;ResolveReferences;GetTargetPath;$(PreNMakeBuildTarget)" Returns="$(NMakeManagedOutput)">
    <VCMessage Code="MSB8005" Type="Warning" Arguments="NMakeBuildCommandLine" Condition="'$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)'==''"/>
    <Exec Command="$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)" Condition="'$(NMakeUseOemCodePage)' == 'true' and '$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)'!=''"/>
    <Exec Command="$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)" UseUtf8Encoding="Always" StdErrEncoding="UTF-8" StdOutEncoding="UTF-8" Condition="'$(NMakeUseOemCodePage)' != 'true' and '$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)'!=''"/>
  </Target>

this is the problem
enter image description here
i tried to reinstall and run the repair on engine after it didint start. And i came here after no online tutorial was of any concrete solution

Working with C++ and Unreal Engine can be challenging as errors can be difficult to interpret. To get a clearer understanding of what's going wrong, I suggest checking the logs in the Visual Studio Output window.
Output Console
Sometimes, issues can be resolved by deleting certain files from the project folder, such as:
.vs
Binaries
Intermediate
.vsconfig
.sln
After deleting these files, you can regenerate the .sln file by right-clicking on the .uproject project file and selecting "Generate Visual Studio Project File".
